# how to concatenate two or more text box values in one text box

Tags: javascript, html

I want to concatenate two or more text box values in one text box.Here I am getting values using id but that id will be dynamically added it means text box will dynamically added.For dynamically adding text box I am using for loop but am getting the value only the last text box value only becaues for loop executed.I want all text box values.Please help me to get me out.Thank you in advance.

Here is the code for dynamic text box process:

In this am using printwriter object in servlet

```
int nums=5;
out.println("<input type='text' id='static'>");

int i;
for (i=0;i<nums; i++) {  
    out.println("<input type='text' Style='width:30px' maxlength='1' id='id"+i+"'onkeyup='sum();'> ");                  

    out.println("<script>function sum(){ alert('id"+i+"'); var txtFirstNumberValue=document.getElementById('id'+i+'').value;var result = document.getElementById('static').value + txtFirstNumberValue;alert(result);if (isNaN(result)){ document.getElementById('static').value = result; }}</script>");
}
```

but if I use static text box I am getting what I need but I need that in dynamic process.

here is the code for static text box process:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="1" id="1"  onkeyup="sum();"/>
<input type="text" maxlength="1" id="2"  onkeyup="sum();"/>
<input type="text" maxlength="1" id="3"  onkeyup="sum();"/>
<input type="text"  id="4"/>

function sum() {
   var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('1').value;
   var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('2').value;
   var txtThirdNumberValue = document.getElementById('3').value;
   var result = txtFirstNumberValue + txtSecondNumberValue + txtThirdNumberValue;
   if (isNaN(result)) {
      document.getElementById('4').value = result;       
   }                        
}
```

Please help me to find out the solution.Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can add a class to all text boxes and later access them in the script by document.getElementsByClassName to loop over the list, you can get each element's attributes to get your final value

Comment: The text boxes don't seem to be dynamically added; dynamically added usually means content is added after the `DOM ready` event. Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: You're using `System.out.println` in javascript. I don't think that's valid javascript. Try using `document.write()` instead.[Official documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)

Comment: *** Why the upvotes, when the question is not even clear? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @PeterKA i just define nums=5 for your understanding purpose only. In real time that nums value dynamically change

Comment: Check generated page source from browser, or put it to here in your question. It will help to resolve your question.

Comment: @AakashJain am not clear can you attach some link for make me to understand

Comment: Why have you included code that is neither JavaScript, not jQuery nor html? It does not help your question.

Comment: Your logic in the server side is wrong?

Comment: @VenkataPanga sir if you getting my requirement can you please tell me the solution

Comment: @PeterKA it is javascript only I am using printwriter object in servlet

Comment: There is a huge difference between `Java` and `JavaScript`. Java is server-side while JavaScript is client-side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would not use inline JavaScript and I would give my elements proper IDs if I really need them otherwise I would use classes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.in').on('input',function() {
    var allvals = $('.in').map(function() { 
        return this.value; 
    }).get().join('');
    $('.out').val( allvals );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="in" type="text" maxlength="1" id="i1"/>
<input class="in" type="text" maxlength="1" id="i2"/>
<input class="in" type="text" maxlength="1" id="i3"/>
<input class="out" type="text"  id="i4"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var cls = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
            var i =0;
            var len = cls.length;
            var tot = 0;
            for(i=0;i<l;i++){
                var cur = cls[i].value;
                tot = parseInt(cur)+tot;
            }
            //document.getElementById("id"+cls.length).value = tot; //set the value for last element as the tot var
        });
    </script>

<body>
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" value="1" id="1" class="test"/>
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" value="2" id="2" class="test"/>
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" value="3" id="3" class="test"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.in').on('input',function() {
    var allvals = $('.in').map(function() { return this.value; }).get().join('');
    $('.out').val( allvals );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="in" type="text" maxlength="1" id="i1"/>
<input class="in" type="text" maxlength="1" id="i2"/>
<input class="in" type="text" maxlength="1" id="i3"/>
<input class="out" type="text"  id="i4"/>
```

Comment: Could you please add a short explanation?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.in').on('input',function() {
    var allvals = $('.in').map(function() { 
        return this.value; 
    }).get().join('');
    $('.out').val( allvals );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="in" type="text"  id="i1"/>
<input class="in" type="text"  id="i2"/>
<input class="in" type="text"  id="i3"/>
<input class="out" type="text"  id="i4"/>
```